# Два условия для равномерного отображения данных в консоли

Tags: java, консоль

```
private static void displayWord() {
    if (count < 9)
        System.out.print(" ");
    if (count < 99)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(++count + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        System.out.print(myChar[i]);
    System.out.print("   ");
    System.out.flush();
    if (count % 6 == 0)
        System.out.println("");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пример из книги. Часть про анаграмы. Отображаются данные ровно. Не ясно назначение  2 и 3 строчки. Они же просто дублируют (подпадают) в следующее условие? Пробелов столько же, условия входит в следующее условие (<99) Но если 2 и 3 строчку убрать - данные разъезжаются. Почему? Как так получается?

Comment: для `< 99` нужно два пробела, для `< 9` хватит и одного. Добавьте в вопрос контекст (непонятно для какой задачи этот код) и, желательно, минимальный пример для запуска

Comment: Добавил уточнение. Но пробелов-то одинаково в обоих условиях. Отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: Я кст неправильно написал -- там наоборот будет. Для числа меньше 9 будет 2 пробела, для числа меньше 99 только один пробел. Не будет одинаково, смотрите. Если `count = 8`, то два пробела (условия `count < 9` + `count < 99`), если `count = 9`, то один пробел  (условие `count < 99`)

Comment: Точно Благодарю.